# CSS borders invisible on page shrink

Tags: css, resize, border, margin

I'm working on a website and I made an example of the problem i have here

http://codepen.io/avovk/pen/pFkmb

It's a 600 page div and the two purple borders that are on the left and right sides are created by setting negative positions on their respective sides. When I drag the browser window to make the page 600 pixels wide or less, the left border disappears, but if i scroll to the right, the right border is still visible. I would like the two borders to only be visible when the page is 600 pixels or wider otherwise the user shouldn't be able to see the right border by scrolling to the right. Kind of like how the left border disappears.

Yes the borders have to be Divs because they're images in my actual website and I would like to do this without javascript.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is with [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries):

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #rightBorder, #leftBorder {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: but then when it's 610 pixels, you can still scroll to see the rest of it. It should partially disappear.

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that in your question... you explicitly said  "I would like the two borders to only be visible when the page is 600 pixels or wider".